# Generics overloading of method - workaround

Tags: java, generics

this question was asked many times but I couldn't find elegant workaround for it.
This example works as desired:

```
public class RequestWrapper<T> {
    private final T request;
    private final Class<T> type;

    public RequestWrapper(T request, Class<T> type) {
        this.request = request;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

public class Service {

    private void invoke(String request) {
        System.out.println("String:" + request);
    }   

    private void invoke(Object request) {
        System.out.println("Object:" + request + "," + request.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RequestWrapper<String> sw = new RequestWrapper<String>("A", String.class);
        RequestWrapper<Integer> iw = new RequestWrapper<Integer>(Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.class);

        new Service().invoke(sw.getRequest());
        new Service().invoke(iw.getRequest());
    }
}
```

But I would need to add one more method to Service class which do something before/after call of invoke method:

```
public void invoke(RequestWrapper<?> wrapper) {
    try {
        // ...
        invoke(wrapper.getType().cast(wrapper.getRequest()));
        invoke(wrapper.getRequest());
    } catch(Exception e ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

then the main method would contain:

```
new Service().invoke(sw);
```

I understand the reason why the invoke(Object request) is used instead of invoke(String request).
What would be an elegant solution to call proper invoke method and be able to do some common actions before/after it?

*To have an interface e.g. Invoker, implement it e.g. StringInvoker, Invoker> and call map.get(wrapper.getType()).invoke(wrapper.getRequest()) is possible solution but I expect something better.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visitor patter can serves to solve it. Only drawback is that there isn't possible to write:

```
new Service().invoke(new RequestWrapper<String>("A"));
```

My implementation:

```
public class Service {
    public void invoke(RequestWrapper<?> wrapper) {
        try {
            // ...
            wrapper.invoke(this);
        } catch(Exception e ) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public void invoke(String request) {
        System.out.println("String:" + request);
    }   

    public void invoke(Boolean request) {
        System.out.println("Boolean:" + request);
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RequestWrapper<Boolean> rw = new BooleanRequestWrapper(Boolean.TRUE);

        new Service().invoke(rw);
    }
}

abstract class RequestWrapper<T> {
    protected final T request;

    public RequestWrapper(T request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public abstract void invoke(Service v);
}

class BooleanRequestWrapper extends RequestWrapper<Boolean> {

    public BooleanRequestWrapper(Boolean request) {
        super(request);
    }

    public void invoke(Service service) {
        service.invoke(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type and explicitly cast it, for example (I also added `Integer` so you can see branching on more types):

```
Class<?> c = wrapper.getType();

if (c == String.class)
    invoke((String) wrapper.getRequest());  // Invokes invoke(String)
else if (c == Integer.class)
    invoke((Integer) wrapper.getRequest()); // Invokes invoke(Integer)
else
    invoke(wrapper.getRequest());           // Invokes invoke(Object)
```

**Note:**

If you go on this path, you don't even need to store the request type in the `RequestWrapper` class because you can just as easily use the `instanceof` operator on the request itself to check its type. And if you "get rid" of the request type, your current `RequestWrapper` class will only contain the request so the `RequestWrapper` is not even needed in this case.

Comment: Yep, but this is exactly what I wanted get rid of. A different idea how to take benefit of method overloading?